# Ubuntu Server Continuously "goes to sleep"

Tags: ubuntu, power-management

I am running a web server at home using Ubuntu 11.4 (maybe? I can't 100% recall) on an older AMD 2400+ desktop with 1 or 2 GB of RAM. Sorry I can't recall the details 100%.

Anyway, I have a KVM hooked up to a monitor and PS2 keyboard that I use to switch between the server and my iMac (The keyboard is only hooked up so I can switch between the two easily. Many times a week, Pingdom will tell me the server is down and I can't hit the server. When I get home (it rarely happens when I am home), I hit the Ctrl key twice to switch to the server, hit the space bar and everything is now up and running again. I need to look again, but I don't believe there is any power saving features turned on in the BIOS.

Does anyone have any other suggestions of what I may have going on? I have my uncle's website running on it now and I really would like to have a better up-time than 95%

As a note, I do not have any GUI installed so everything has to be done on the console (or through WebMin) and I know my way around, but I am by no means experienced.

Comment: Does anything appear in system logs (files under `/var/log`)?

Comment: Any logs I should look at in particular?

Comment: I don't know, look for log entries in any file (probably `kern.log`, but possibly others) created around the time the computer went to sleep.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add the kernel options `acpi=off apm=off` to the contents of  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in file `/etc/default/grub`

Then run `sudo update-grub`

Finally reboot your computer.

Comment: Nope, I'll try that.

Comment: Well... I made the change. Only time will tell if it works.

Comment: I need to figure out why yet, but the server just "went down" again.

Comment: Those kernel options should have completely disabled automatic power management.  Did you rebuild grub with the `update-grub` command?

Comment: Nope... I was wondering if there was a step two. :-(

Comment: And step three would be to reboot with the new kernel configuration... ;)

You can verify the options are active with a `cat /proc/cmdline`

Comment: Okay... ran `update-grub' and rebooted and confirmed it's active. Try again...

Comment: This seemed to have resolved my problems. I am waiting it out a couple weeks before marking this as the answer.

Comment: No downtime after a week. I am guessing this was the answer.

Comment: This worked to prevent a Debian standard install from sleeping when closing a laptop lid, although it also prevented the screen resolution from switching to the native. Luckily I just SSH in, so no problems there.

Comment: This prevented my Ubuntu 14 server from booting. It complain about things like "failed to obtain physical IRQ 9" when doing ehci-pci initialization.

Comment: This caused USB devices to stop working with Ubuntu Server 14.04.3.

Answer (score 17):

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I successfully used the following to disable suspend:

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

And this to re-enable it:

```
sudo systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

Answer (score 6):

> Add the kernel options acpi=off apm=off to the contents of
>   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in file /etc/default/grub
>
> Then run sudo update-grub
>
> Finally reboot your computer.

According to https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Bootoptionen its a bad idea to turn off acpi complete as it may cause overheating because of turning off fan control.

This is a very old question. Just for other people who may have similar issue check `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` if it fits to the configuration you need. It may be that `IdleActionSec` is set to an unusual high value and `IdleAction` is set to `suspend`.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to the end of your kernel parms in `/boot/grub/grub.conf`:

```
consoleblank=0
```