# Ubuntu Server goes to standby mode

Tags: ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu Server 12.04 in a virtual machine (VMware Workstation) and it seems like the system goes to standby, at least the first request on a webserver installed on it takes quite long and the "virtual monitor" goes to standby.

How can I disable this sleep mode?

Please note I alraedy searched for this problem and had a look at [Ubuntu Server goes to standby mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25133/ubuntu-server-continuously-goes-to-sleep), however that didn't help in my case ):
Thanks for any hint!

Comment: The TTY going blank is not the server itself going into standby, just the display. The slow first request is likely because it has to read data from disk that is otherwise cached in RAM.

Comment: It could be the server's memory had been paged out; how busy is your machine?