# Wireless network slow speed, inconsistant connection : "Intel Dual Band Wireless - AC 3165"

Tags: networking, wifi, networkmanager

I'm using Deepin 15.4.1.

**Here is my system network config info:**

## Network Devices

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 79)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:4410]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 282
    Region 0: Memory at df200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee00358  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [40] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <512ns, L1 unlimited
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset+ SlotPowerLimit 0.000W
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr+ NoSnoop+ FLReset-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L1, Exit Latency L0s <4us, L1 <32us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range B, TimeoutDis+, LTR+, OBFF Via WAKE#
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 16ms to 55ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR+, OBFF Disabled
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -3.5dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap- CGenEn- ChkCap- ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [140 v1] Device Serial Number 68-07-15-ff-ff-e3-87-08
    Capabilities: [14c v1] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Max snoop latency: 3145728ns
        Max no snoop latency: 3145728ns
    Capabilities: [154 v1] L1 PM Substates
        L1SubCap: PCI-PM_L1.2+ PCI-PM_L1.1+ ASPM_L1.2+ ASPM_L1.1+ L1_PM_Substates+
              PortCommonModeRestoreTime=30us PortTPowerOnTime=60us
        L1SubCtl1: PCI-PM_L1.2+ PCI-PM_L1.1+ ASPM_L1.2+ ASPM_L1.1+
               T_CommonMode=0us LTR1.2_Threshold=163840ns
        L1SubCtl2: T_PwrOn=60us
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Dell RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1028:0781]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 278
    Region 0: I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at df104000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Region 4: Memory at df100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee002d8  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 01
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 10.000W
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 4096 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <64us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+, LTR+, OBFF Via message/WAKE#
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR+, OBFF Disabled
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
        Vector table: BAR=4 offset=00000000
        PBA: BAR=4 offset=00000800
    Capabilities: [100 v2] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [140 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Capabilities: [160 v1] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
    Capabilities: [170 v1] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Max snoop latency: 3145728ns
        Max no snoop latency: 3145728ns
    Capabilities: [178 v1] L1 PM Substates
        L1SubCap: PCI-PM_L1.2+ PCI-PM_L1.1+ ASPM_L1.2+ ASPM_L1.1+ L1_PM_Substates+
              PortCommonModeRestoreTime=150us PortTPowerOnTime=150us
        L1SubCtl1: PCI-PM_L1.2+ PCI-PM_L1.1+ ASPM_L1.2+ ASPM_L1.1+
               T_CommonMode=0us LTR1.2_Threshold=163840ns
        L1SubCtl2: T_PwrOn=150us
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
2 of 19 matched [nN]etwork|[eE]thernet
0 of 6 matched [nN]et|[eE]thernet
```

## Network Status

```
enp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 18:db:f2:0d:b5:ba  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 652  bytes 37560 (36.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 652  bytes 37560 (36.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.109  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::6c1b:6228:d2df:74fb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 68:07:15:e3:87:08  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 12735  bytes 12928014 (12.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10974  bytes 1872622 (1.7 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"ziroom"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: BC:46:99:A6:13:C6   
          Bit Rate=150 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=57/70  Signal level=-53 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:17582   Missed beacon:0
```

## NetworkManager Configuration

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

## NetworkManager State

```
nmcli 工具，版本 1.2.4
Status    Connection  WIFI-HW  WIFI    WWAN-HW  WWAN   
OK        Full        Open     Open    Open     Open
```

## NetworkManager Hotname

```
zhangsh-PC
```

## NetworkManager Permissions

```
权限                                                       值   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-network      y   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wifi         y   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wwan         y   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wimax        y   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.sleep-wake                  y   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control             y   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected        y   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open             y   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system      y   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own         y   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.hostname    y   
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.global-dns  unknown 
org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.reload                      y
```

## NetworkManager Logging

```
级别  域                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
INFO  PLATFORM,RFKILL,ETHER,WIFI,BT,MB,DHCP4,DHCP6,PPP,IP4,IP6,AUTOIP4,DNS,VPN,SHARING,SUPPLICANT,AGENTS,SETTINGS,SUSPEND,CORE,DEVICE,OLPC,INFINIBAND,FIREWALL,ADSL,BOND,VLAN,BRIDGE,TEAM,CONCHECK,DCB,DISPATCH,AUDIT,SYSTEMD
```

## NetworkManager Connections

```
名称        UUID                                  类型             设备   
ziroom      f45a457b-a5e0-48b2-87db-ae21a4b6a008  802-11-wireless  wlp2s0 
mi6    2fd80ca5-b4bf-4ca6-9b99-6e7c2ae7d9b3  802-11-wireless  --     
eth 1  f8b22fa8-5a52-39d5-b535-578dbf26f005  802-3-ethernet   --
```

## NetworkManager Devices

```
设备    类型       状态         连接   
wlp2s0  wifi      connected  ziroom 
enp3s0  ethernet  unsupported  --     
lo      loopback  unhosted     --
```

## NetworkManager Wireless Access Points

```
*  SSID              模式  频段  速率       信号  BARS  安全性    
*  ziroom            红外  11    54 Mbit/s  67    ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 
   HHT_10_2_173_10_  红外  3     54 Mbit/s  55    ▂▄__  WPA2      
   105302_24         红外  11    54 Mbit/s  42    ▂▄__  WPA2
```

## ModemManager State

```
No modems were found
```

## Wireless Device Switches(rfkill)

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

## Network Interface File

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

## DNS Configuration(resolv.conf)

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 114.114.114.114
```

## Route Table

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0
```

Comment: @GAD3R Issue happens when I'm using the computer. You mean this? [question about power management](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25133/ubuntu-server-continuously-goes-to-sleep/25151#25151)

Comment: Create a `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` file with the following line `options iwlwifi power_save=0` then reboot Or you can test it before with `iw dev wlp2s0 set power_save off`

Comment: @GAD3R Thanks a looot, I'll try it later and reply. Hope it works!

Comment: @GAD3R Still not working......What should I do next?

Comment: Try `modrobe -rv iwlwifi` then `modprobe -v iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 swcrypto=1 11n_disable=8`

Comment: @GAD3R modprobe: FATAL: Module iwlwifi is in use.
How do I fix it, can I use `modprobe -rv iwldvm` instead?

Comment: @GAD3R I removed iwldvm and iwlmvm module first, then I did as you mentioned above,  and it finally works!!!!! I can watch video stable now!!!!Thanks a looot!!! Really appreciate!

Comment: > `sudo rmmod -f iwldvm`
> `sudo rmmod -f iwlmvm`
> `sudo modprobe -rv iwlwifi`
> `sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 swcrypto=1 11n_disable=8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` with the following options:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0
options iwlwifi swcrypto=1
```

It will enable antenna aggregation ,disable Bluetooth coexistence  and enable software encryption.

Comment: You may consider 11n_disable=1 , this worked by far the best for me, even with omitting the other two options. Also power_save=0 may be helpful too.