# CentOS 7 on Macbook Pro halts after some time of inactivity

Tags: centos, macintosh

I had a space Macbook Pro which I installed minimal centos 7 on it to use it as a server machine. To make sure the machine never turns off, I modified the `logind.conf` to the following:

```
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
HandleSuspendKey=ignore
HandleHibernateKey=ignore
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=no
IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=no
#UserTasksMax=
```

Still after some time of inactivity, I cannot ssh to the machine anymore. When I go to the machine, the screen is on but does not show anything (not the terminal login prompt). I have to hard shutdown and restart to make it work again.

I could not find anything in the log files on why the machine halted. Any clue how to resolve this?

Thanks

**Update:**
I noticed the computer's screen is turned off 10 minutes after inactivity. I suspect whatever module is responsible for turning off the screen (ACPI? APM?) causes the hang as well. But I have no idea how to investigate this further.

Comment: Sometimes the system hangs after only a 1.5 hours. I leave the lid open and keep the screen on, but still, this happens.

Comment: minimal install it's always a little vague; I have a Cent OS 7 minimal install, but, probably, our systems are very different from each other... I get `gsettings` by default in my minimal install, but I don't have any schemes; check that in your system: maybe you have `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power` and you need to set some keys to zero; check your BIOS/UEFI too: maybe is something there.

Comment: Check `systemctl status sleep.target hibernate.target suspend.target hybrid-sleep.target` too; maybe you can try to mask them.

Comment: See this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25133/ubuntu-server-continuously-goes-to-sleep

Comment: Thanks, @matsib.dev. My `gsettings` also is empty and has no schemes. The `systemctl` command that you mentioned also all returns `inactive`. Also, Macbooks don't have BIOS AFAIK. So I couldn't really check anything there. I will check the post you sent.